# Gitlab-CI with Docker executor /usr/bin/bash: line 90: git: command not found

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a local GitLab server and gitlab-ci runner with Docker executor.

I want to use gitlab-ci to build (for the first stage) my Maven project. Since I use buildnumber-maven-plugin I added a Git service to my gitlab-ci.yml like this:

```
image: maven:latest

services:
  - alpine/git:latest

# Cache goes here
cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository
    - frontend-app/node_modules/

# ENV variables goes  here

# Before script goes here

# Stages definition goes here
stages:
  - build

# Build stage
build:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - mvn --version
    - git --version
  script:
    - mvn clean install --settings .ci/settings.xml
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - backend-app/target/*.jar
```

But when `git --version` is executed I got `command not found error`.
This is my complete GitLab CI console log:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 12.9.0 (4c96e5ad)
   on securteck jrEY4-V2
Preparing the "docker" executor
 Using Docker executor with image maven:latest ...
 Starting service alpine/git:latest ...
 Pulling docker image alpine/git:latest ...
 Using docker image sha256:fe3295a34a932155290fdbba14d770c11f3dfe0e1e732d8e355cecbeec59e877 for alpine/git:latest ...
 Waiting for services to be up and running...
 *** WARNING: Service runner-jrEY4-V2-project-1-concurrent-0-alpine__git-0 probably didn't start properly.
 Health check error:
 ContainerStart: Error response from daemon: Cannot link to a non running container: /runner-jrEY4-V2-project-1-concurrent-0-alpine__git-0 AS /runner-jrEY4-V2-project-1-concurrent-0-alpine__git-0-wait-for-service/service (docker.go:1322:0s)
 Service container logs:
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.826814609Z usage: git [--version] [--help] [-C <path>] [-c <name>=<value>]
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.826879457Z            [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.826895945Z            [-p | --paginate | -P | --no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.826910244Z            [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.826923359Z            <command> [<args>]
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.826935482Z 
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.826947063Z These are common Git commands used in various situations:
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.826959005Z 
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.826971038Z start a working area (see also: git help tutorial)
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.826982664Z    clone     Clone a repository into a new directory
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.826994349Z    init      Create an empty Git repository or reinitialize an existing one
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.827006426Z 
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.827017832Z work on the current change (see also: git help everyday)
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.827029626Z    add       Add file contents to the index
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.827040891Z    mv        Move or rename a file, a directory, or a symlink
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.827052743Z    restore   Restore working tree files
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.827064196Z    rm        Remove files from the working tree and from the index
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.827075878Z 
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.827087305Z examine the history and state (see also: git help revisions)
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.827099305Z    bisect    Use binary search to find the commit that introduced a bug
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.827111245Z    diff      Show changes between commits, commit and working tree, etc
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.827125099Z    grep      Print lines matching a pattern
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.827137183Z    log       Show commit logs
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.827149113Z    show      Show various types of objects
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.827160630Z    status    Show the working tree status
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.827172589Z 
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.827183674Z grow, mark and tweak your common history
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.827195529Z    branch    List, create, or delete branches
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.827207168Z    commit    Record changes to the repository
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.827218764Z    merge     Join two or more development histories together
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.827230406Z    rebase    Reapply commits on top of another base tip
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.827241931Z    reset     Reset current HEAD to the specified state
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.827253929Z    switch    Switch branches
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.827265678Z    tag       Create, list, delete or verify a tag object signed with GPG
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.827277537Z 
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.827300897Z collaborate (see also: git help workflows)
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.827314706Z    fetch     Download objects and refs from another repository
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.827327136Z    pull      Fetch from and integrate with another repository or a local branch
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.827339235Z    push      Update remote refs along with associated objects
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.827351266Z 
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.827362364Z 'git help -a' and 'git help -g' list available subcommands and some
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.827374869Z concept guides. See 'git help <command>' or 'git help <concept>'
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.827387595Z to read about a specific subcommand or concept.
 2020-04-10T19:05:54.827401411Z See 'git help git' for an overview of the system.
 *********
 Pulling docker image maven:latest ...
 Using docker image sha256:32cd4e857a56c5cfddaafaebc877764e2547e7bc23b4bc63cfc6a163c4ee3361 for maven:latest ...
Preparing environment
00:02
 Running on runner-jrEY4-V2-project-1-concurrent-0 via PAR-174582...
Getting source from Git repository
00:03
 Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
 Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/securteck/securteck/.git/
 From http://195.154.233.19:8000/securteck/securteck
  * [new ref]         refs/pipelines/29 -> refs/pipelines/29
    b8a890e..17b4d1c  develop           -> origin/develop
 Checking out 17b4d1cd as develop...
 Skipping Git submodules setup
Restoring cache
00:02
 Checking cache for default-4...
 No URL provided, cache will not be downloaded from shared cache server. Instead a local version of cache will be extracted. 
 Successfully extracted cache
Downloading artifacts
00:02
Running before_script and script
00:02
 $ mvn --version
 Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
 Maven home: /usr/share/maven
 Java version: 14, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/java/openjdk-14
 Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
 OS name: "linux", version: "4.15.0-76-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
 $ git --version
 /usr/bin/bash: line 90: git: command not found
Running after_script
00:02
Uploading artifacts for failed job
00:02
 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like, you can install `git` in your `maven` container.  Example (stub) `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: maven:latest

myjob:
  script:
  - yum install -y git
  - git --version
```

From the CI job log:

```
$ git --version
 git version 1.8.3.1
```

Comment: Your solution is to install git every time Job is running? Seems not so good to me.

Comment: I agree @RomanMitasov -- would be better to use a maven container that already has git in it.

Answer (score 5):

A service is another docker container running during your job (a database for example). The docker image `alpine/git:latest` is not a *service*, it is used to execute a git command. You can see in your logs that `git` is called without a command.

Instead of using a `service`, you should use a docker image with `git` installed in it to run your job. This way, your script will be able to call `git`.

Comment: So If I understand your response, I should use a docker image with both maven and git inside??

Comment: Yes, use an image with both maven and git installed instead of using the service mechanism.

Comment: mmmmm, do you know such docker image with both maven and git inside :) ?

Comment: You have one with Maven already, you can install git on it.   :)

Answer (score 2):

The error is occurring, because the **git** is not available on the runner which picked up your build for execution.

As discussed in previous posts, using services is not efficient.

```
services:
  - alpine/git:latest
```

And also, installing git every-time on your image is time consuming and resource heavy.

```
myjob:
  script:
  - yum install -y git
  - git --version
```

So, the most efficient approach is to use the image with git installed upfront and perform your git task.

Below is my example, where I am using an image of **alpine/git** from dockerhub https://hub.docker.com/r/alpine/git and executing my job on a container launched from this image.

```
create-git-tag:
  image: alpine/git
  stage: tag
  script:
    - git --version
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when working to deploy a Go app to AWS using GitLab CI.

Here's the error code I got:

```
$ echo "Check the go version"
Check the go version
$ go version
/bin/bash: line 128: go: command not found
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

**Here's how I fixed it**:

The issue was that I did not specify an image (`image: golang:latest`) for the job (compile job):

```
stages:
  - test
  - build
  - deploy

format:
  stage: test
  image: golang:latest
  script:
    - go fmt $(go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/)
    - go vet $(go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/)
    - go test -race $(go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/)  # Test code

compile:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Check the go version"
    - go version  # Display the go version
    - go get -d -v   # Get all go dependencies
    - mkdir -p mybinaries  # Create binaries directory
    - go build -o -v mybinaries ./...  # Build go application and save to a directory
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - mybinaries
  environment:
    name: development
  only:
    - dev
```

All I had to do was to specify an image (`image: golang:latest`) for the job (compile):

```
stages:
  - test
  - build
  - deploy

format:
  stage: test
  image: golang:latest
  script:
    - go fmt $(go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/)
    - go vet $(go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/)
    - go test -race $(go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/)  # Test code

compile:
  stage: build
  image: golang:latest
  script:
    - echo "Check the go version"
    - go version  # Display the go version
    - go get -d -v   # Get all go dependencies
    - mkdir -p mybinaries  # Create binaries directory
    - go build -o -v mybinaries ./...  # Build go application and save to a directory
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - mybinaries
  environment:
    name: development
  only:
    - dev
```

I could also specify the image globally (`image: golang:latest`) at the top of the script:

```
image: golang:latest

stages:
  - test
  - build
  - deploy

format:
  stage: test
  script:
    - go fmt $(go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/)
    - go vet $(go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/)
    - go test -race $(go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/)  # Test code

compile:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Check the go version"
    - go version  # Display the go version
    - go get -d -v   # Get all go dependencies
    - mkdir -p mybinaries  # Create binaries directory
    - go build -o -v mybinaries ./...  # Build go application and save to a directory
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - mybinaries
  environment:
    name: development
  only:
    - dev
```