# Gitlab CI/CD fail with "bash: line 132: go: command not found"

Tags: go, gitlab

We have installed Gitlab on our custom server. We are looking to use the gitlab CI/CD pipeline to build and release our software for that I'm working on a POC. I have created a project with the following `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
variables:
  GOOS: linux
  GOARCH: amd64

stages:
  - test
  - build
  - deb-build

run_tests:
  stage: test
  image: golang:latest
  before_script:
    - go mod tidy
  script:
    - go test ./...


build_binary:
  stage: build
  image: golang:latest
  artifacts:
    untracked: true
  script:
    - GOOS=$GOOS GOARCH=$GOARCH go build -o newer .

build deb:
  stage: deb-build
  image: ubuntu:latest
  before_script:
    - mkdir -p deb-build/usr/local/bin/
    - chmod -R 0755 deb-build/*
    - mkdir build
  script:
    - cp newer deb-build/usr/local/bin/
    - dpkg-deb --build deb-build release-1.1.1.deb
    - mv release-1.1.1.deb build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - build/*
```

[image]

TLDR: I have updated the gitlab-ci.yml and the screenshot of the error.

What I have noticed, the error is persistent if I use the shared runner(GJ7z2Aym) if you register a runner (i.e Specific Runner)

[image]

```
gitlab-runner register  --non-interactive  --url "https://gitlab.sboxdc.com/"   --registration-token "<register_token>" --description ""  --executor "docker" --docker-image "docker:latest"
```

I see the build passing without any problem

Failed case.

https://gist.github.com/meetme2meat/0676c2ee8b78b3683c236d06247a8a4d

One that Passed

https://gist.github.com/meetme2meat/058e2656595a428a28fcd91ba68874e8

Comment: The file you show doesn't have 132 lines.

Comment: Can you check `cat config.toml | grep executor` after running `gitlab-runner register ...` shown in the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The failing job is using a [runner with `shell` executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/shell.html), that was probably setup when you configured your GitLab instance. This can be seen on logs by this line:

> ```
> Preparing the "shell" executor
> Using Shell executor...
> ```

`shell` executor will ignore your job's `image:` config. It will run job script directly on the machine on which the runner is hosted, and will try to find `go` binary on this machine (failing in your case).  It's a bit like running `go` commands on some Ubuntu without having `go` installed.

Your successful job is using a [runner with `docker` executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html), running your job's script in a `golang:latest` image as you requested. It's like running `docker run golang:latest sh -c '[your script]'`. This can be seen in job's logs:

> ```
> Preparing the "docker" executor
> Using Docker executor with image golang:latest ...
> Pulling docker image golang:latest ...
> Using docker image sha256:05e[...]
> golang:latest with digest golang@sha256:04f[...]
> ```

---

What you can do:

1. Make sure you configure a runner with a `docker` executor. Your `config.toml` would then look like:

```ini
[[runners]]
  # ...
  executor = "docker"

  [runners.docker]
  # ...
```

It seems you already did by registering your own runner.

2. Configure your jobs to use this runner with [job `tags`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#tags). You can set tag `docker_executor` on your Docker runner ([when registering or via Gitlab UI](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/configure_runners.html#use-tags-to-control-which-jobs-a-runner-can-run)) and setup something like:

```yaml
build_binary:
  stage: build
  # Tags a runner must have to run this job
  tags:
  - docker_executor
  image: golang:latest
  artifacts:
    untracked: true
  script:
    - GOOS=$GOOS GOARCH=$GOARCH go build -o newer .
```

See [Runner registration](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/index.html#runners-configuration-template-file) and [Docker executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html) for details.

Comment: Another solution is installing go compiler in runner machine manually, if the asker have terminal access to that machine. Although adopting container testing method is better choice overall when other testing requirements considered.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have used `image: golang:latest`, `go` should be in the $PATH

You need to check at which stage it is failing: `run_tests` or `build_binary`.
Add `echo $PATH` in your script steps, to check what $PATH is considered.

Check also if the error comes from the lack of `git`, used by Go for accessing modules remote repositories. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71953928/6309) as an example.

From your gists, the default GitLab runner uses a [shell executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/shell.html) (which knows nothing about Go)

Instead, the second one uses a [Docker executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html), based on the Go image.
Registering the [(Docker) runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/register/#docker) is therefore the right way to ensure the expected executor.

Comment: It is failing in the run_tests also the stuff work without any hassle If I register the docker runner as explain the above comment.

Comment: @Viren Can you add a `variables: CI_DEBUG_TRACE: "true"` in your job (as [in here](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/how-to-see-step-script-contents/72587/2)). And display `env` to see the environment variables?

Comment: it quite verbose

Comment: @Viren Sure, I suppose it is verbose. The goal is to check if, within that verbose output, there is a clue as to why the runner fails to resolve Go. Try the same with a registered runner, and see if there is any difference between the two runs.

Comment: Added the gist.

Comment: @Viren Can you do the same with a registered runner, one where `go` is recognized?

Comment: Done added the passed one as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250309/discussion-between-vonc-and-viren).